# Is there any good reason to use 'id' as return type or parameter type in public API?

Tags: objective-c, types, return-type

I am learning from [Stanford's CS193P course](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/). In the class, Paul has a demo project, "Calculator", where he uses `id` as the type of a property. He intends to not use a specific class, because he does not want to create a new class and then he does not need to write documentation, and even when it is  updated, he does not need to redesign the class. `id` can solve all these problems.

Is this a really a good way? `id` is the return type of the property, and used as the parameter type of another method. How does the caller know what `id` is, and how to provide the correct object? By reading code comments?

In general, is there any good reason to use `id` as a return type or parameter type in public API? (Except `init` and factory method, though even for those, `instancetype` is recommended.)

Comment: Note that `instancetype` [is redundant for a method whose name begins with `init`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#related-result-types).

Comment: The most common place to run into `id` where it's really ambiguous is when accessing an element in something like a JSON-generated NSArray or NSDictionary.  In such cases it may be necessary to explicitly test at runtime to determine what type is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If your method returns a class that is a member of a class cluster, you should return `id`.
2. If you're returning an object whose class is opaque, isn't declared in a public header, you should return `id`.  (Cocoa occasionally uses such objects as tokens or context data.)
3. Container classes should always accept and return their constituents as `id`s.

Comment: I knew 3rd. for #2, it's really a good example:context or token which caller does not change it, just use it as reference and pass it to different APIs. For #1, I think caller still can not change it, just keep a reference for future use.

Comment: more question, for #2, Do you have any real example?

Comment: For #2, there are two examples I can think of: the `AVPlayer`'s `addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:` method returns an opaque context object that is used when the player calls back.  Second, In 10.4 `NSPersistentStore` was opaque -- when you queried a coordinator for it's `persistentStore`, you'd get an `id` back.